# Unauthorized access to the RabbitMQ API

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-rabbit

I am trying to accomplish each time when I start my app, to get from the RabbitMQ API, all the queues and exchanges that exist. But unfortunately I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: [no body]
```

My code:

**application properties** file :

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=localhost

spring.rabbitmq.port=5672

spring.rabbitmq.username=guest

spring.rabbitmq.password=guest

spring.rabbitmq.addresses=localhost:8080/api/

rabbitmq-api-url = http://localhost:8080/api/
```

**Component** that executes each time on startup:

```
@Component
public class StartupCLass implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    @Value("${rabbitmq-api-url}")
    private String endpoint;


    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(endpoint+"queues",String.class);
    }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:

I have some queues and exchanges defined on my RabbitMQ server. I have also exported the definitions json file and modified it with renaming some of the queues/exchanges. I want to check when starting the app, which queue or exchange has been renamed regarding the json file and the current state of the rabbit mq server (that's why I want to get from the API the queues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

401 means unauthorized. So you have to pass username and password in the request.

```
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(
  new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("username", "password"));
```

Read more here:
https://www.baeldung.com/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring